# ubuntu 18.04 close lid doesn't suspend properly

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell, laptop

my computer is DELL XPS 13 9380

recently I noticed that when I close the lid, it doesn't suspend properly
and when I open the lid, the screen will be stuck at this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LDto.jpg)

I'll have to hit super+L to suspend it and wake it up again

what confused me is that if I hit super+L directly instead of closing the lid, everything works just fine

I have tweak tools installed and set the
**suspend when laptop lid is closed** to true

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: FYI, super+L is 'Lock Screen' - Please try this to get more info: 1. Watch logs with `tail -f -n100 /var/log/syslog`, 2. run a suspend command with another term `sudo systemctl suspend`, 3. wake it up and copy/paste the logs in https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add the link

Comment: @cmak.fr thanks for the reply ,  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YYdQ8DfDh6/ this is the log